# Magento 2: Is there any way to set "Maximum/Minimum Order Total" Config settings for PayPal express checkout And Braintree credit card payment method?

Tags: magento2.3, sales-order, payment-methods, paypal-express, gene-braintree

I want to add a minimum and maximum order total configuration for **PayPal express checkout** and **Braintree credit card** payment method. Just like bank transfer/ cash on delivery payment methods.

I tried with adding field in system.xml using custom module. but the min/max total is not validating in frontend.

Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Comment: You will have to define isAvailable() method in the payment model files. You will have to obviously override the models

Comment: define configuration from any of your module's system.xml and you can use "payment_method_is_active" observer

Comment: @GohilRajesh Thanks! it worked.

Comment: great then adding answer.

Comment: you can update answer if you want to add specific information so it can be helpful to someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define configuration from any of your module's system.xml and you can use `payment_method_is_active` observer.